# Weird border background in place of ripple below api 23

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, android-4.4-kitkat, android-design-library

I am using design support library. But everyplace where ripple supposed to be seen is showing some image on border.

This is happening below lollipop. Here is the screenshot 
[image: weird ripple image]

Comment: I think the image you are using is 9 patch image. Can you check this file extension. if it is *.png then change it to *.9.png

Comment: I am not using any image. Maybe it is getting generated by android system. The view is CardView.